# How to Convert Row data to Column without Onehot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a data set like below.

```
MonthDate   DayCategory
Jan-01         Federal Holiday
Jan-19         Federal Holiday
Jan-23         Event
Jan-31         Event
Feb-14         Event
Feb-16         Federal Holiday
Feb-19         Federal Holiday
Feb-22         Federal Holiday
```

I want this list like below list

Output List should be like below using Python Code:

```
    Month   FederalHoliday  Event
    Jan         2            2
    Feb         3            1
```

Please help me on this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is the data being stored / read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have dates instead of month as string, You can use:

```
pd.crosstab(df.MonthDate.dt.strftime('%b'),df.DayCategory).rename_axis(None,1)

           Event  Federal Holiday
MonthDate                        
Feb            1                3
Jan            2                2
```

Comment: Thanks Anky. With your code, Months are sorted out with Alphabets and Months are taking as Index. I do not want indexing on month. I want data frame with Month, Event and Holiday. Thanks

Comment: How to remove indexing on Month? I need this dataframe to merge with other dataframe. Thanks Anky.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df.MonthDate.dt.strftime('%b'),df.DayCategory).rename_axis(None,1).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

For correct ordering need ordered categoricals, for count use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
cats = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr','May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug','Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
md = pd.to_datetime(df['MonthDate'], format='%b-%d').dt.strftime('%b')
#alternative
#md = df['MonthDate'].str.split('-').str[0]
df = pd.crosstab(pd.Categorical(md, categories=cats, ordered=True), 
                 df['DayCategory']).rename_axis('Month').reset_index()

df.columns.name = None
print (df)
  Month  Event  Federal Holiday
0   Jan      2                2
1   Feb      1                3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot_table(index=df["MonthDate"].str[:3], columns="DayCategory", aggfunc="count")
```

Comment: please provide additional content as to why this would be a solution.